# How realized binding in silverlight on low-level?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, low-level

On my interview (Silverlight project) my interviewer asked me "How realized binding in Silverlight on low-level". Could, please, anyone tell how it's work?
I really tried to google it, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check information about

- [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) Interface
- [Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)
- [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
- [Data Binding How-to Topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752039.aspx)